# CMD cURL сохранить полученные cookie в файл

Tags: curl

Есть такой запрос:

```
curl "https://apps.allrecipes.com/v1/assets/hub-feed?id=78^&pageNumber=2^&isSponsored=true^&sortType=p" \
  -X OPTIONS \
  -H "Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors" \
  -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" \
  -H "Origin: https://www.allrecipes.com" \
  -H "Referer: https://www.allrecipes.com/recipes/78/breakfast-and-brunch/" \
  -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36" \
  -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,x-requested-with" \
  --compressed
```

Как сохранить c полученный cookie в файл на диске?

Пытался через cURL в php, но не сохраняет ничего, как будто куки не приходят. Хотя при выполнении этого запроса через Postman - видно что куки приходят.

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

```
curl ... -c my-cookie-jar
```

см. [`man curl`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=curl&category=1) за подробностями

Comment: Не сохраняет ничего. Как будто куков не приходит. Я пробовал так уже

Comment: @iKey, значит сервер на этот запрос ничего не возвращает... добавь `-vvvv` и посмотри, что он на самом деле отвечает...

Comment: @iKey, собственно похоже ты и делаешь только [предварительный](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/preflight_request) запрос, который и не должен возвращать ничего осмысленного...